# When I store my big text file into arraylist the size is only 4?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundEsxception;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Benford {
    static Object            i    = null;
    static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static String    data;

    public static void BenfordPercents() {
        int one   = 0;
        int two   = 0;
        int three = 0;
        int four  = 0;
        int five  = 0;
        int six   = 0;
        int seven = 0;
        int eight = 0;
        int nine  = 0;

        return;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DrawingPanel g       = new DrawingPanel(500, 500);
        Graphics     brush   = g.getGraphics();
        String       popData = null;

        readCount(popData);
        BenfordPercents();
    }

    public static void readCount(String popdata) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Please make sure the data file is name popData.txt");
        System.out.println("We are loading popData.txt...");

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Scanner console = new Scanner((new File("popData.txt")));

        try {
            i = new FileInputStream("popData.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("We cannot locate popData.txt");
            System.out.println("Please make sure popData.txt is in the same location" + " as your code file!");

            return;
        }

        System.out.println("popData.txt has loaded!");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please press enter to show data!");
        data = console.nextLine();

        File            file   = new File(popdata + ".txt");
        FileInputStream fis    = new FileInputStream("popdata.txt");
        byte[]          flush  = new byte[1024];
        int             length = 0;

        while ((length = fis.read(flush)) != -1) {
            list.add(new String(flush));

            // System.out.println(new String(flush));
            // System.out.println(list.toString());
        }

        // Scanner x = new Scanner((new File("popData.txt")));
        // while(x.hasNext()){
        // list.add(x.next());
        // }
        fis.close();
    }
}
```

I have a text document with all the numbers of populiation from this link here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population

The text document looks like this:

```
China   1369480000
India   1270250000
United  320865000
Indonesia   255461700
Brazil  204215000
Pakistan    189607000
..etc
..etc
```

the list is pretty long.

and when I try to store all of these numbers into an array list and I try to print the array list size it just returns 4?

Comment: can you share the output of your list

Comment: If the size is only four, then it only added for elements to the arraylist which means that your reader is failing before it gets to the end of the file.

Comment: and your text file..may be there is a problem with encoding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a large text file line by line using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java)

Comment: You are not reading it line by line, but by chunks of 1024 bytes. You need to use a BufferedReader and ready by line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list-entry for each line, you should prefer a BufferedReader.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("popdata.txt")
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

while((String line = br.readLine()) !=null) {
    list.add(line);
}
```

The size of 4 is only the size of your arraylist - each element of your array list was build from an byte-array with a length of 1024. This means that your list either contains about 3K until 4K of data.